# Which multiprocessing pool method to use?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In for loops, there are some tasks that can be called and run in parallel.
But we need to accumulate the result of each task on the same data structure.

```py
class Accumulator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.signal = np.zeros((10000,), dtype=float)
        self.count = np.zeros((10000,), dtype=int)

    def on_result(self, result):
        self.signal += result[0]
        self.count += result[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    num_proc = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_proc)

    accumulator = Accumulator()
    for chrName in chrNames:
        for simNum in sims:
            pool.apply_async(func, (chrName,simNum,), callback=accumulator.on_result)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(accumulator.signal)
    print(accumulator.count)
```

Which python multiprocessing pool method is the best in terms of runtime and memory usage?

```py
Apply or map or imap?
```

```py
sync or async?
```

Is there a runtime/memory benchmarking for these possibilities?

Comment: Not to be flippant, but why don't you check and see for yourself? Fundamentally, these are empirical questions that will undoubtedly depend on the particulars of your use-case.

Comment: In fact, I tested for map and apply.async and map took 1 hour 11 minutes  with 30 GB of memory and apply_async took 53-54 minutes with 37GB of memory. Memory usage may not be reliable though.  But if there was a detailed benchmarking available, it would be great.